# Can’t get microphone sound in Android system

Tags: audio, android, microphone

I am currently working on developing voice recognition functionality using Unreal Engine for both Windows and Android platforms. I have implemented the related functionality in C++. Since the target Android version is 7.1.1, I am using Unreal Engine version 4.23 for development. In my code, I have utilized AudioMixer functionality, but since AudioMixer in 4.23 is considered a new feature, I had to create an AndroidEngine.ini file and add [Audio] UseAudioMixer=true to enable it.

I have configured both the Engine.ini files for Windows and Android. I have noticed that when I package and run the application on Windows, everything works fine. However, when I package it for Android, I cannot capture audio from the microphone. I have tested the microphone using the Android device's built-in voice recorder, and it seems to work correctly. I have also granted recording permissions for my project on the Android system. However, I still cannot capture any microphone audio, and I have checked the locally saved WAV file in my application, which does not contain any sound.

I find this situation quite puzzling, and I hope someone can provide me with some guidance on how to resolve this issue.